# How can we add system timezone to datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to format time to add system timezone at the end of datetime.

```
select date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')  ;
```

Output i am getting as

> 2018-06-06T10:00:18Z

But the expected output is

> 2018-06-06T10:00:18.+05:30

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have briefly read the MySQL reference of `date_format()` and `convert_tz()`  functions and observed that no such syntax is supported.

So, I came up with this sql:

```
select concat(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%dT%T'),'.',@@global.time_zone);
```

This query returns:

```
2018-06-06T19:46:46.SYSTEM
```

> How to deal the 'SYSTEM' mess?

The `@@global.timezone` is initialized from your **config file** so if it is set to System's time, the variable can't be anything more than that.

**Solution:**

You should have covered your programming language in question for better answer. Anyways, after running this query you must check if the query has returned the timezone as `SYSTEM`, if it is, ask your system to tell it's timezone.

Let others know, if it worked. :)